# Swift compiler crashes at custom delegate method

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a custom delegate below is the code for that

```
import UIKit
protocol SAlertViewDelegate {
func clickedButtonTitle(_ title:String?,alertTag:Int?)
}
func button1Action(_ sender: UIButton?) {

    let titleLabel=sender?.titleLabel?.text
    self.delegate?.clickedButtonTitle(titleLabel!,alertTag: alertTag!)
    removeFromMainView()
}
```

Implementing this delegate method in a viewController

```
func clickedButtonTitle(_ title:String?,alertTag:Int?)
{
  print(title)
}
```

While building the project it showing the error

> Showing Recent Messages
>   Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
>   1.  While emitting SIL for 'clickedButtonTitle'

The same code is working fine on swift 2.3 , but not in swift3.

Answer (score 0):

In your protocol declaration, the function signature does not need (nor want) the internal variable name.

So

```
protocol SAlertViewDelegate 
{
   func clickedButtonTitle(_ title:String?,alertTag:Int?)
}
```

should be

```
protocol SAlertViewDelegate 
{
   func clickedButtonTitle(_ :String?, alertTag:Int?)
}
```

This may or may not be the only reason for the error.  It is hard to tell when you get a segmentation fault.

Your other code snippets are out of context, so it's hard to tell what else could be causing the problem.